# Transform and Stacking Order

Tags: css, z-index, css-transforms

I am trying to understand what is really happening “3d” world of CSS.
I made a simple [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dXvEWw)

Particularly the code which bugs me the most is:

```
.back {
    background-color: tomato;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    z-index: 1;
}
```

The thing which is not clear to me is why when you hover over .inner, its background color (gold) is not visible?? If you remove the transform property from .back or if you set the rotateY to 0deg then the gold background color of the .inner is clearly visible.
Why is the transform property of .back changing the stacking order?

Logically it makes sense that children(.front and .back) should appear in front of their parent(.inner).

Also, I would like to know what really happens when you set transform-style to flat? Does that make parent and all of its children collapse into single “unit” where element with highest stacking order takes priority/visibility?

Comment: This demo explains it better, http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QErrNm. This time I have used translateZ instead of z-index. It just aint clear why .back appears in front of his parent when you hover over .inner.

Comment: May be you are expecting this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kXopkW

Comment: Yes, thats what I wanted to achieve. Can you please explain why it behaves differently when you move translateZ after rotateY? Also how can this be modified to use z-index instead translateZ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code :

```css
.outer {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid gold;
  perspective: 1000px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.inner {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transition: transform 2s linear;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  background-color: gold;
  backface-visibility: visible;
  transform: rotateY(50deg);
}

.sides {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  color: white;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.front {
  background-color: blue;
  transform: translateZ(20px)
}

.back {
  background-color: tomato;
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(10px);
}

.inner:hover {
  transform: rotateY(180deg)
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="sides front">Front Side</div>
    <div class="sides back">Back Side</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

you are using

```
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(10px);
```

The transforms are applied right to left, so first it goes to the front 10px. But after that, it rotates 180deg. (around the transform-origin that is constant). That makes the previous 10px go towards the back instead of to the front.

if the order is the inverse

```
  transform: translateZ(10px) rotateY(180deg);
```

now the rotation is done first, and so the translation is unafected by it and goes to the front.

and **No**, sorry, z-index is not a substitute for 3-d transforms, if you want to use 3d transforms, translation is the only way to go ....

In your first example, z-index is useless, as can be seen easily

[codepen with z-index removed](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/grGKvK)

This works because you are setting

```
backface-visibility: hidden;
```

So only the face that is facing front will be visible

Comment: Thanks, thats it. Its clear and it makes sense. Just one more thing about z-index. In the first example translateZ is not used, only z-index, I am wondering why .back appears in front of the .inner when you hover over that element? Thanks Vals, I am a new(bie) user so I can not upvote your response, even though you deserve it.

Comment: Thanks, but the .inner is rotated on hover and it has backface-visibility: visible, why its gold background is not shown when rotated?

Comment: Anyway, I really appreciate your help, answer is marked as approved.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't pay attention to inner, I was looking only to front and back... In this case, if there isn't further instructions, children will draw above the parent. Also, in some cases, z-index can still work. But if you really want to work in 3d, try to stick using transforms and translate to set the proper visualization of the elements.